# STUCK at Turning!!!!!! Navigation help!

Tags: localization, gazebo, rviz, costmap, local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

please help guys. [image: image description]

Please refer to the picture. As you can see, whenever the robot is turning, it will stuck at the corner. It just stays at there instead of performing recovery plan, back up, etc. But then you don't have a sharp turn like this, navigation works great. It would be awesome if you guys could help to debug a little, because I had already investigated with the params offered by the stacks. Thank you all in advance.

Here is my configuartion.

```
TrajectoryPlannerROS:
  max_vel_x: 1.0
  min_vel_x: 0.2
  max_rotational_vel: 1.6
  min_rotational_vel: 0.2
  min_in_place_rotational_vel: 0.2

  acc_lim_th: 2.2
  acc_lim_x: 2.5
  acc_lim_y: 2.5
  holonomic_robot: false
  goal_distance_bias: 0.8
  path_distance_bias: 0.8  #[working on 8.0]
  occdist_scale: 0.01
  heading_lookahead: 0.325
  dwa: false
  escape_vel: -0.8
  
  sim_time: 1.0
  sim_granularity: 0.025
  vx_samples: 3
  vtheta_samples: 20

  yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.8 # about 6 degrees
  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.2 # 5 cm
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65646/stuck-at-turning!!!!!!-navigation-help!/) by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 146 on 2013-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your costmap looks like the robot should not be in collision. It seems like the reason why it is colliding is likely to be one of two things.

A) Improper footprint parameter - Increasing the size of the footprint (to maybe include the wheels?) would increase the inflation of the wall obstacle.

B) Also miiiiiiiiiight be a localization problem.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2013-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on 2013-06-21**:
it's A.  Thank you and fixed.

also, I have one more question about the "path_distance_bias" and "goal_distance_bias", If I want the robot to follow the global plan ( that I see in the Rviz), then I should increase the "path_distance_bias" right?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2013-06-21**:
I believe so. Are you not seeing that behavior?

**Comment by [RodrigoCatto](https://answers.ros.org/users/63903/rodrigocatto/) on 2021-08-20**:
Regarding "path_distance_bias" and "goal_distance_bias" there is a good explanation in this tuning guide: https://kaiyuzheng.me/documents/navguide.pdf